# Access/Render Xml Objects

Tags: xml

hi guys i am trying to display xml data in react that has been parsed/converted to json..
i have pushed the data in state and have mapped over it but i am not able to access the following:
1-S:tag object
2-image src which is in summary object
3-s:type
4-s:variant

i can access simple properties like the title etc but i have no idea about accessing the above mentioned properties/objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json) to parse xml to json

Edit 1: If you can access `title` as `items.title` you can access `s:type` like,

```
items["s:type"]
```

Edit 2:

Say, you have another state object as `summary`

```
  var parser2 = new FeedMe(true);

  parser.on('end', () => {

     //console.log(parser.done().items);
    this.setState({
      summary:parser.done().items
    })
    console.log("state", this.state.summary);

  });

  this.state.item[0].summary.pipe(parser);
```

Now, your this.state.summary will have the json of the `summary` from initial object. Now after this conversion you can use, `this.state.summary.table.tr.td.img`(not sure how the resultant json will look like, but this way it should work)

Comment: the data has already been converted to json..i need to know a way of rendering the properties asked in my question..like how do i access them..jsx doesnt let me use {items.s:type} as it gives an error..however, i can access items.title or id

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the json in a proper format.

Comment: i have added a screenshot

Comment: You can use the same xml to json convertion for the value of `items.summary` and from that json, traverse to that object and get the image.

Comment: sorry..this went right over my head..can you explain it in a simpler way please

Comment: In the question u said u have converted xml to json, right? And the value for `items.summary` which contains `<table border...` is also an xml. Now you can use the xml to json conversion mechanism to this value and the resulting json can be used to get the value of image.

Comment: In the mean time can you please accept the answer and upvote it for stack overflow community.

Comment: i have added my code..can you please take a look..i am using feedme.js to parse the xml

Comment: i tried using your code in multiple ways..it either gives me an error saying summary is undefined,if i remove [] from item it says pipe is undefined and lastly the code just works till my first console.log and doesnt do anything for the second part parser2...